# Bona fide; genuine; authentic: what's the difference?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm really confused here.

The dictionary definitions overlap, and memorizing them only confuses me further.

I would really appreciate some tips on this matter.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate of: [_genuine_ vs. _authentic_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449102); [_original_ vs. _genuine_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133332); [meaning of _authenticity_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16551/); opposites of [_pretentious_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331737) and [_superficial_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248001); [Usage of 'bona fide'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56667); [Why 'buy authentic'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66456)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following definitions and usage examples from the [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bona%20fide&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) clearly explain its  meaning and usage:

Bona fide:

> 1) Made or carried out in good faith; sincere: *a bona fide offer.*
>
> 2) ***Authentic; genuine***: *a bona fide Rembrandt*.

As noted by the [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/bona-fide-bona-fides/):

> The phrase bona fide comes directly from the Latin bona fides, which means, roughly, good faith. ***In modern English, bona fide (without the s) is usually an adjective meaning (1) made or carried out in good faith or (2) real or genuine.***

Answer (score 0):

**Bona fide:**

A Latin phrase that literally means "in good faith" and generally means good intentions and complete absence of deceit. As in:

> Even though the results turned out to be questionable, it was a *bona
>   fide* attempt to make things right.

**Genuine:**

This adjective denotes the truthfulness, actuality, and legitimacy of an item or matter. The original Latin word means "natural."

> The antiques they have to offer are *genuine*, not fake.

**Authentic:**

Not a copy. Not a knock-off. The real McCoy.

> The Rembrandt they sold at that auction is most certainly *authentic*,
>   and you'd know this if you'd taken the time to examine closely some of
>   its aspects.